# Can the Banach-Tarski paradox or Tarski's circle-squaring problem be done with hinges?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, banach-tarski

It is known for both *the Banach-Tarski paradox* and *Tarski's circle-squaring problem* that you can finitely partition the starting configuration, then continuously move these pieces (without intersection) into the final configuration using isometries.

Is it known if these continuous movements can take the form of a hinged dissection?

---

Since the pieces used in either result aren't simple shapes, here are some extra details:

- A hinge between two pieces $A$ and $B$ can be any point in $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$ (where $\bar{X}$ denotes the topological closure of $X$).
- The pieces in either result aren't necessarily connected. But that's fine, in such a case a disconnected piece can still rotate around the hinge as a "fixed shape".
- In *the Banach-Tarski paradox* the final configuration is two disjoint spheres. To make this a valid hinged dissection problem, the final configuration should be taken to be two spheres with boundaries sharing exactly one point in common.
- In three (or higher) dimensions I am defining a hinge to be a point-like hinge, as something like an edge-like hinge is hard to even define for the types of pieces in these problems.

---

The formal definition of a hinged dissection is a bit tedious, but was requested and is now given here for completeness:

> A hinged dissection from $A$ to $B$ consists of the following:
>
> 1. a finite partition $P_1,...,P_n$ of $A$
> 2. a collection of time-dependent isometries $\sigma_t^1,...,\sigma_t^n$ which depend continuously on $t$
> 3. a collection of hinges $(h_1,\{P_{i_1},P_{j_1}\}),...,(h_m,\{P_{i_m},P_{j_m}\})$, such that for all $k \in \{1,...,m\}$:
>
> - $h_k \in \bar{P}_{i_k} \cap \bar{P}_{j_k}$
>
> satisfying the following:
>
> 1. $\sigma_0^1,...,\sigma_0^n$ are all the identity isometry
> 2. for each $t \in [0,1]$ we have that $\sigma_t^1[P_1],...,\sigma_t^n[P_n]$ are disjoint sets
> 3. $B = \bigcup_{k=1}^n \sigma_1^k[P_k]$
> 4. for each hinge $(h_k,\{P_{i_k},P_{j_k}\})$ we have $\sigma_t^{i_k}(h_k) = \sigma_t^{j_k}(h_k)$
> 5. given any two pieces of the partition $P_\alpha$ and $P_\beta$, there exists a finite sequence of hinges $(h_{f(1)},\{P_{i_{f(1)}},P_{j_{f(1)}}\}),...,(h_{f(r)},\{P_{i_{f(r)}},P_{j_{f(r)}}\})$ satisfying:
>
> - $P_\alpha = P_{i_{f(1)}}$ and $P_\beta = P_{j_{f(r)}}$
> - $P_{j_{f(k)}} = P_{i_{f(k+1)}}$

Here is an animation of what a hinged dissection is supposed to look like (though it is a little misleading since I'm not requiring the hinges to be located on the boundary of the pieces due to their pathological shape):

[image]

Comment: The 'big' pieces in Banach-Tarski are all dense in the sphere, so it should be pretty easy to do the standard decomposition using only hinged movements. (By 'big,' I mean positive outer measure.) Moving the small piece around should also be pretty straightforward, so I would guess the normal proof can be adapted to work here too.

Comment: Historical note: the original hinged dissection was a four-piece dissection of an equilateral triangle to a square, due to Dudeney, in 1907. See, e.g., https://web.nmsu.edu/~pbaggett/Lessons/T2S/Triangle2Square.htm

Comment: @JamesHanson Sorry but I'm not sure how the pieces having positive outer measure means they can be moved by hinge movements. Care must be taken to make sure that the pieces don't intersect during the continuous motions.

Comment: @SamForster Ah sorry, I didn't understand that they needed to not intersect.

Comment: I think the question is, at the moment, unclear. Could you give a careful definition of “hinged dissection”, and what kinds of “hinge movements” are allowed?

Comment: @HJRW I have added a formal definition of what I mean by hinged dissection.